# Did -webkit-backface-visibility break today in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, css, webkit, transform

I'm a bit confused because my project worked yesterday but seems to no longer work correctly today. (Yes, I've checked previous versions from git.)

The problem: Some divs previously hidden with `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` magically appeared.
I have isolated this issue into a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Js6cg/1/

The div is visible in Chrome at `23.0.1271.64 m` (wrong) but hidden in `25.0.1326.0 canary` (as I expected).

**Can you confirm that this is indeed a bug in Chrome or am I using the CSS incorrectly somehow?**

(I've updated my GPU drivers (AMD Catalyst) from 12.8 to 12.10 today, if that's important.)

---

Additionally, the [site that demonstrates the effect I've been reproducing](http://css3playground.com/flip-card.php) appears to work +- correctly at Chrome stable (except for aparrently ignoring `-webkit-perspective` and animating kind of choppy), while Chrome canary renders it very well and accepts the perspective. I'm confused.

Comment: Addendum: Same Chrome version, different PC = works; I think I'm going to bug report that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, that is embarassing.

The story looks like: I've updated the GPU drivers but looks like I haven't actually restarted Chrome for ages. For some reason, it was unable to re-enable GPU compositing after the driver update and hence some more advanced CSS3 effects (like `perspective` and `backface-visibility`) didn't work at all, while simple transforms used a fallback CPU implementation, which also made them look choppy and on the demo site.

I've started Chrome Canary well after the driver update, so it didn't have any issues with GPU compositing. One instance worked, another didn't, but version mismatch wasn't important here at all.

Restarting Chrome fixed that issue. And I'm taking a break!